# backbone-forms how do I submit the generated form in Backbone rest?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-forms

I have [this use-case](http://jsfiddle.net/evilcelery/4XZMb/) (The official example of backbone-forms).
What is the correct way to add a submit button and send the form restfully to server using backbone?
I want to use backbone capabilities to restfully speak with the server while the form values are binded to the Model.

Or [in my use-case](http://jsfiddle.net/JDNug/1/):

```
<form id="theForm"></form>

$(function () {
    var Login = Backbone.Model.extend({
        initialize: function () {

        },
        defaults: {
            Email: "",
            Password: ""
        },
        schema: {
            Email: {
                validators: ['required', 'emailj']
            },
            Password: {
                validators: ['required']
            },
        },
    });

    var login = new Login({
        Email: "Your email please",
        Password: "password"
    });

    var form = new Backbone.Form({
        model: login,
    }).render({
        fieldsets: 'fieldsets'
    });
    $('#theForm').append(form.el);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usual way is to create a 'master' Backbone view that contains the submit button, then insert the form into that.  Then handle the submit click event from within your master view.  That would be done by doing `form.commit()` to set it on the model, and then calling `model.save()`

Comment: thanks for your answer, since I am very new in both technologies, any change you can add it to this fiddle so Ill have a good reference? http://jsfiddle.net/JDNug/1/? thanks again!

Comment: Here's an updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/JDNug/7/

Note that there will be an error when it tries to save because your Login model doesn't have a url property.

Another way, which might make more sense, is to change the Form template to include a submit button. See the backbone-forms docs for that.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, Can you please tell me, can I hook the error message and put it in a balloon, i mean, is there any event that I can take the message and do what ever I want with it? thanks again

Comment: The error that's appearing in the jsfiddle example is from backbone itself, not backbone forms. You'll need to add the URL property to the model for it to work at all. You could put a try/catch block around model.save() though. For form errors eg validation, you can get them through form.validate()